# How to avoid the small page movement in a react component at first load

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, storybook

There is a reusable Radio Group component which works fine but it has a small issue, first time it is loaded and the user selects an options it moves fast (maybe re-renders?).

After that it doesn't have the issue anymore but cannot find its root cause.

Here is the code:

**radio-button.stories.tsx**

```
import { ComponentMeta } from '@storybook/react';
import { useState } from 'react';

import RadioButtonGroup from './radio-button-group';
import { IOptionGroup } from './radio-button.types';

export default {
  title: 'Components/RadioButton',
  component: RadioButtonGroup,
} as ComponentMeta<typeof RadioButtonGroup>;

const Template = ({ ...args }: IOptionGroup) => {
  const options = [
    {
      label: 'Coffee',
      name: 'button-types',
    },
    {
      label: 'Tea',
      name: 'button-types',
    },
    {
      label: 'Disabled option',
      name: 'button-types',
      disabled: true,
    },
  ];

  const [selectedValue, setSelectedValue] = useState<string>(options[0].label);

  function radioGroupHandler(event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) {
    setSelectedValue(event.target.value);
  }

  console.log('selectedValue: ', selectedValue);

  const label = 'Select an option:';

  return (
    <RadioButtonGroup
      {...args}
      options={options}
      label={label}
      onChange={radioGroupHandler}
      horizontal
    />
  );
};

export const button = Template.bind({});
```

**radio-button-group.tsx**

```
import RadioButton from './radio-button';
import { Legend, Fieldset, Horizontal, Vertical } from './radio-button.styles';
import { IOption, IOptionGroup } from './radio-button.types';

export const RadioButtonGroup = ({ label, options, horizontal, onChange }: IOptionGroup) => {
  function getRenderedOptions() {
    return options.map(({ label, name, disabled }: IOption, index) => {
      const shortenedOptionLabel = label.replace(/\s+/g, '');
      const optionId = `radio-option-${shortenedOptionLabel}`;

      return (
        <RadioButton
          value={label}
          label={label}
          key={`${optionId}-${index}`}
          id={optionId}
          name={name}
          disabled={disabled}
          defaultChecked={index === 0}
          onChange={onChange}
        />
      );
    });
  }

  const renderedOptions = horizontal ? (
    <Horizontal>{getRenderedOptions()}</Horizontal>
  ) : (
    <Vertical>{getRenderedOptions()}</Vertical>
  );

  return (
    <Fieldset>
      <Legend>{label}</Legend>
      {renderedOptions}
    </Fieldset>
  );
};
export default RadioButtonGroup;
```

**radio-button.tsx**

```
import { StyledRadioButton, Radio, Wrapper } from './radio-button.styles';
import { RadioButtonProps } from './radio-button.types';

export const RadioButton = ({ label, id, disabled, ...rest }: RadioButtonProps) => {
  return (
    <Wrapper>
      <Radio type="radio" id={id} disabled={disabled} {...rest} />
      <StyledRadioButton htmlFor={id}>{label}</StyledRadioButton>
    </Wrapper>
  );
};

RadioButton.displayName = 'RadioButton';

export default RadioButton;
```

**radio-button.types.ts**

```
import { InputHTMLAttributes } from 'react';

export type option = string | number;
export interface RadioButtonProps extends InputHTMLAttributes<HTMLInputElement> {
  label: string;
  id: string;
  key: string | number;
  disabled?: boolean;
}

export interface IOption {
  label: string;
  name?: string;
  disabled?: boolean;
}

export interface IOptionGroup {
  label: string;
  options: IOption[];
  onChange: (e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => void;
  horizontal?: boolean;
}
```

**radio-button.styles.ts**

```
import styled from 'styled-components';

export const Fieldset = styled.fieldset`
  border: none;
`;

export const Vertical = styled.div``;

export const Horizontal = styled.div`
  display: flex;
  gap: 1rem;
`;

export const StyledRadioButton = styled.label<{ disabled?: boolean }>`
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: black;
`;

export const Legend = styled.legend`
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: black;
`;

export const Wrapper = styled.div`
  display: flex;
  gap: 1rem;
  margin-top: 0.5rem;
  margin-bottom: 0.5rem;
  align-items: center;
`;

export const Radio = styled.input`
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  margin: 0;
  width: 1.5em;
  height: 1.5em;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-style: normal;
  border-radius: 50%;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all 0.1s ease-in-out;
  ::after {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    border-radius: 50%;
    width: 0.75em;
    height: 0.75em;
    margin: 4.26px;
  }
  :checked {
    ::after {
      background-color: blue;
    }
    border: 1px solid green;
  }
  :hover {
    border: 1px solid red;
  }
  border: 1px solid red;
  :disabled {
    cursor: not-allowed;
    border: 1px solid grey;
    background-color: grey;
    :checked {
      ::after {
        background-color: grey;
      }
    }
  }
`;
```

Here is a video of the issue: https://www.dropbox.com/s/j5nx2vpiscmbvxm/Screen%20Recording%202023-01-02%20at%2022.28.45.mov?dl=0

Comment: The problem seems to be in the font-family that is rapidly changing. I'm not sure if it is really related with the radio. Is hard to analyze without having the code where they are embedded.